# Prevent mouse pointer from highlighting item in inactive window?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse

Whenever my mouse cursor is over an inactive window, many apps will highlight content and fool me into thinking the window is active.  As someone who is used to focus follows mouse in other desktop environments, this leads to me trying to type content in an inactive window.  This makes it possible to cause the actual active application to do something destructive.

> For example, I have an xterm in a virtual desktop.  The cursor becomes solid and the xterm titlebar looks active.  This tricks me into believing that I am free to type into it.  Unfortunately, my virtual desktop is inactive, and Thunderbird is.  My keypresses are now causing Thunderbird to mark, delete, or any other number possible of things to occur to my email.

Is there any way to prevent windows applications from responding to the mouse cursor, when their window is inactive.

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight content" exactly?

Comment: For example, I have an xterm in a virtual desktop.  The cursor becomes solid and the xterm titlebar looks active.  This tricks me into believing that I am free to type into it.  Unfortunately, my virtual desktop is inactive, and Thunderbird is.  My keypresses are now causing Thunderbird to mark, delete, or any other number possible of things to occur to my email.

Comment: If you prefer X-mouse behavior, **you can make focus follow mouse** in Windows, too. The settings for Windows 7 are in the *Ease of Access* control panel applet; see http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/9000-mouse-hover-makes-window-active-enable.html.

Comment: Windows focus follows mouse is horrible.  It breaks a lot of applications and the auto-raise behavior is unpleasant.  I just want to configures apps to follow intuitive click to focus-follows-mouse behavior and not do anything when a mouse is above the window.

Comment: @Juan: you can turn of window autoraise, which I agree is very annoying. If you want focus follow mouse pointer in Windows (to enable typing and keyboard commands in the program under the mouse pointer) I'd recommend also [tweaking the hover delay with my open source utility](https://joelpurra.com/projects/X-Mouse_Controls/) X-Mouse Controls instead of registry hacking.